# Утечка памяти при отправке сообщения через smtp

Tags: c#, .net

Из-за следующих строк происходит утечка памяти:

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(mail, mail, "?", "");
msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(filePath, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain));
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru", 25);
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(mail, "password");
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Send(msg);
client.Dispose();
msg.Attachments.Dispose();
msg.Dispose();
```

Можно ли решить эту проблему? Вроде все dispose вызвал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dispose не освобождает память. Он просто просит класс уничтожить неуправляемые ресурсы(всякие там handles и прочее, что там внути client используется).

Память в .net освобождается недетерминированно, сборщиком мусора. Течет - это когда потребление памяти растет со временем, при каждом вызове вашего кода. А у вас - просто не освобождается мгновенно, так и задумано.

Comment: Эта часть кода вызывается один раз, но в диспетчере задач постоянно увеличивается потребление ОЗУ программой

Comment: @KnowNamed тогда вам стоит взять профайлер памяти и поискать реальную утечку

Answer (score 1):

Вместо явного вызова `Dispose()` лучше использовать [using](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

```
using(var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru", 25))    
using(var msg = new MailMessage(mail, mail, "?", ""))
{
    msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(filePath, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain));
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(mail, "password");
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.Send(msg);    
}
```

Уничтожать `Attachment` не имеет смысла, он сам уничтожится при уничтожении сообщения